# Reversed order of WP query loop based on latest 3 posts of category

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show:

1. The latest 3 posts of a category based on the publish date [this part works].
2. But show them in an asc order based on a meta value [this does not work yet].

The meta value is a custom date of a podcast.

To show the latest 3 posts of the category it does this based on the publishing date (which is fine), but then you get this:
1 April | 1 March | 1 February

*Above are the custom post meta fields. Because 1 April is published the latest it shows first.*

It should be **reversed** while still showing the latest 3 posts of the category based on the publish date.

Desired outcome: 1 February | 1 March | 1 April

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I have ideas.  I could even probably do this.  However, this is a site for help with _programming questions_, and it's expected that you'd share what you have done so far to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The orderby parameter can accept multiple values in an array. This will sort the found posts a second time.

Take a look at the documentation for more info:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Other approach can be to loop over the found posts and determine their order based on the meta value. You can rearrange them in a new array and use that for the output.

As cale_b says, if you want a more specific answer please share what you already have.